# создание .msi пакета без прав администратора (setup project)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, install

У меня стоит задача - создать инсталляционный файл для своего софта. При использовании Visual Studio Setup Project создается .msi инсталлятор, но на windows 7 для его установки на обычном пользователя запрашивается пароль администратора. Собственно мне нужно, чтобы при установки обычным пользователям ничего не запрашивалось. Из очевидного, установка идет в папку, доступ к которой есть у пользователя(рабочий стол для проверки), окно выбора папки установки я убрал. Записи в реестр тоже убрал. Из-за чего такое может быть и как убрать запрос прав администратора? (Использование других упаковщиков, таких как InnoSetup - не подходит, антивирус удаляет такие инсталляторы у пользователей, так же не всегда подобные программы имеют достаточный функционал(нужно создавать .ini файл с настройками введеными пользователем во время установки))

Comment: 1) Никогда не делайте инсталяцию для пользователя на рабочий стол, делайте например в `%localappdata%` 2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080131/how-to-make-a-setup-work-for-limited-non-admin-users

Comment: Тот же результат. На рабочий стол делал для 100% уверенности, что для этого не нужны права администратора

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostBuildEvent или командная строка:
path C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17763.0\x86 MsiInfo.exe "C:\yourPath\file.msi" /w 10